# Criar uma lista de tuplas extraindo uma str de um txt

Tags: python, lista, txt, tuple

Tenho um txt chamado 'layout1.txt' com a seguinte estrutura:

```
specs6;[(0,2),(2,17),(17,32),(32,47),(47,62),(62,72)]
specs7;[(0,2),(2,17),(17,32),(32,42),(42,52),(52,83)]
```

Tenho o seguinte código para iterar no arquivo e buscar uma linha específica:

```
with open('layout1.txt', 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as layout:
for line in layout:
    if line.startswith('specs6') == True: #identifica a linha que vou usar
        colspecs = line[7:0] #fatia a string, usando apenas o que vem após 'specs6;'
```

Esperava que a variável colspecs recebesse a string já a considerando como uma lista de tuplas, porém o formato é str.

Preciso que a linha retirada do arquivo seja armazenada na variável colspecs como uma lista de tuplas, tal qual:

```
colspecs = [(0,2),(2,17),(17,32),(32,47),(47,62),(62,72)]
print(colspecs)
print(type(colspecs))
```

Output do exemplo acima:

```
[(0, 2), (2, 17), (17, 32), (32, 47), (47, 62), (62, 72)]
<class 'list'>
```

Comment: A solução mais simples seria: `colspecs = eval(line[7:0])`. Porém, pode ser uma falha de segurança. Imagine se no seu arquivo tiver uma linha como `specs6;rm -rf *` ou `specs6;DROP DATABASE` ou sei lá... Muito cuidado ao usar o `eval`

Comment: @PauloMarques, dá uma olhada na [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/536707/137387) pois acho que vai o interessar.

Comment: @AugustoVasques, obrigado pela dica.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avalie com segurança uma string contendo um literal Python com a função [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval). A string fornecida deve consistir apenas nas seguintes estruturas literais do Python:

- strings
- bytes
- números
- tuplas
- listas
- dicionários
- conjuntos
- booleanos
- None
- Ellipsis

`ast.literal_eval()` pode ser usado para avaliar com segurança strings contendo valores Python de fontes não confiáveis sem a necessidade de analisar os valores por si próprio. Não é capaz de avaliar expressões arbitrariamente complexas, por exemplo, envolvendo operadores ou indexação.

Aplicado no código da pergunta:

```python
from ast import literal_eval

with open('layout1.txt', 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as layout:
  for line in layout:
    if line.startswith('specs6') == True: 
        colspecs = literal_eval(line[7:])     # Avalia o literal contido na string 
        break

print(type(colspecs))                         # Imprime o tipo do literal avaliado.
print(colspecs)                               # Imprime o literal avaliado.
#<class 'list'>
#[(0, 2), (2, 17), (17, 32), (32, 47), (47, 62), (62, 72)]
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@Augusto-Vasques/specs6#main.py)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Tente isso aqui:

```py
file = open("layout_1.txt", "r");
content = file.read().split("\n");
file.close();

colspecs = [];
for line in content:
    if line.find("specs6") >= 0:
        temp = line[9:(len(line)-2)];
        temp = temp.split("),(");
        for element in temp:
            element = element.split(",")
            element[0] = int(element[0]);
            element[1] = int(element[1]);

            colspecs.append((element[0],element[1]));

print(colspecs);
```

Básicamente, eu:

1. Li o conteúdo do arquivo.
2. Criei um loop para iterar sobre as linhas
3. Filtrei as linhas que contém: "specs6"
4. Usei o [split](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp) para converter as linhas em vetores, usando os: "),(" como separadores.
5. Criei um segundo loop que itera sobre cada novo vetor (temp) e adiciona seus elementos no formato tupla: `(element[0], element[1])` a lista colspecs, utilizando a função [append](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_append.asp)